# Creating a makefile for C program

Tags: c, makefile

Can anybody please help me to create a makefile for this program? I've tried to to one but it does not work... Thank you!

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "MakeArg.c"

int main()   
{   
char cmdline[256];   
char **argv;   

printf("doit# ");   

for (;;)   
{      
    scanf("%s",cmdline);   
    if (strcmp(cmdline,"q")==0)   
        break;   
    else   
    {   
        printf("doit# ");    
        if (fork()==0)   
        {   
            if (MakeArg(cmdline," ",&argv)>0)   
                execvp(argv[0],argv);   
        }   
        wait(NULL);   
    }   
 }   
 exit(0);   
}
```

Here is what I have for now, but it does not work:

```make
CC         = gcc 
CFLAGS     = ­-c -­Wall -­ansi ­-pedantic 
SOURCES    = MakeArg.c doit.c 
OBJECTS    = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)  
EXECUTABLE = doit
all: $(EXECUTABLE) 
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
$(CC) -­o $@ $(OBJECTS) 
%.o: %.c $(HEADER) 
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -­o $@ $< 
clean: 
rm ­f *.o $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: please post the errors you are getting

Comment: ur way of asking question is too poor. Pls provide more detail. You didn't say what the error was and it seems little effort from ur side.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few errors:

**1) You will also need to include the following headers in the file you have posted:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

**2) In your clean target in your makefile, you are missing the '-' in front of 'f'. Should be rm -f.**

**3) Also, make sure you have a tab character(instead of spaces) before each recipe in the Makefile.** 
It's hard to tell if you did(or didn't do) this from your post.

**4) Also, it's not recommended to include a .c file.**

Try something like this:

```make
CC         = gcc
CFLAGS     = ­-­Wall -­ansi ­-pedantic 
SOURCES    = MakeArg.c doit.c
OBJECTS    = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)  
EXECUTABLE = doit

all: $(EXECUTABLE) 

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean: 
    $(RM) ­-f $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

//

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include "MakeArg.h"

int main()   
{   
char cmdline[256];   
char **argv;   

printf("doit# ");   

for (;;)   
{      
    scanf("%s",cmdline);   
    if (strcmp(cmdline,"q")==0)   
        break;   
    else   
    {   
        printf("doit# ");    
        if (fork()==0)   
        {   
            if (MakeArg(cmdline," ",&argv)>0)   
                execvp(argv[0],argv);   
        }   
        wait(NULL);   
    }   
 }   
 exit(0);   
}
```

Comment: Did this answer help?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to accept answers that answer your question by clicking the check mark beside the answer.